# How to tune parameters batch by batch?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, clustering

As the title states, I am trying to cluster a huge dataset and cluster it by using `sklearn.Birch` to learn incrementally.

If it's a small dataset, I could just use gridsearchcv.

However, there's no built-in way to do that with large dataset in scikit-learn right now.

I'm curious if there is any suitable/general way to tune parameters batch by batch?

Answer (score 0):

In **Grid Search, Random Search**, we trained different independent model i.e. irrespective of the outcome of previous models and later evaluate all these independent models.

> We have another automatic technique for hyper-parameter optimization,
>   known as Bayesian  HyperOpt.

It took the references of previous model and try to identify the best new set of hyper param and trained a new model.
This two step process gets repeated, until we get the desired results.

You can get many online references for complete implementation.

Although I could not find any approach for batch by batch, I thought its worth to mention Bayesian approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library for big data - dask, and in particular dask-ml. This library will allow you to work with large datasets that do not fit into memory by implementing batch learning. Dask-ml also has [grid_search_cv](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#dask_ml.model_selection.GridSearchCV).